# Do I have to deallocate dynamic array in qb64?

Tags: qb64, quickbasic

I learnt about making dynamic arrays in quick basic. The question is, do I have to use the erase statement if a dynamic array is defined inside a function or memory will be freed up itself

I want to understand whether qb64 deallocates dynamic array at the end of a function or not